# Can I Use a 32-bit Library in a 64-bit Build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a library that other developers use in their projects. I am wondering if I must recompile my binary for 64-bit in order to work in projects that compile 64-bit slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need a 64-bit library.